Need help to organize 2D AABB collision engine quad node structure
In short:
I'm writing my custom 2d collision engine in C and I've chosen to use quad nodes to optimize collision detection. My implementation defines 2 things: the quad node (Quad_s) and the elements (Element_s) which look like this:
struct Quad_s {
    struct Quad_s *parent;
    struct Quad_s **children[4];
    size_t elementsize;
    struct Element_s *elements;
};

struct Element_s {
    int x, y, w, h;      // AABB
    struct Quad_s *node; // The node that contains the AABB of element.
};

What I want in my custom implementation is to take in consideration the bounding box of the elements (AABB), so my bodies have an actual fixed area in the space and aren't just a single point.
These elements may be between multiple nodes or be bigger than nodes, so I've implemented that when an element is added to the root, moves or resize it will find or create the best child node that fit his whole size until it reach a leaf. This makes elements to be inside any location between the root to the leafs in the hierarchy.
Then I had the idea that collision would simply detect starting from the element current node all the way up of the parents, but I've got to a realization:
A big element, which is nearest to the root node, if it only goes up to check collision it will never check a leaf node that contains an intersecting element because my implementation only goes up.
The problem:
Find another way to store elements on the leafs ... or add more weight to the collision detection ... or ???.

My first solution I came up with is to add in my implementation to first go down in the node children for the specific case of big elements.
Another is to make a single list of elements and then make the node
tree store multiple references of the same object that fit in
multiple leaf node, I haven't figured out or tested how to do so but
I think it may be expensive for all the computation needed to reach
each leaf and adding in multiple arrays.

Does it exist another way that could keep me to just check going up the hierarchy? Because I really like how that works.

How large of world or is it just the screen?  How many objects and their sizes? Are you separating moving objects and fixed objects?

For most 2D games on modern computers, a grid structure is much more performant and offers a fixed access time, at the possible cost of using more memory. Depending on the distribution of entries: a full world of evenly distributed objects using Quad-trees, uses 4 times the depth of the tree more memory than a properly sized grid structure.

@agone (1) The world size is a rectangle and I want to make this engine work with any size greater than 1 on both axys.
(2) IDK the max amount of objects I should expect this engine should run, but I expect to get good performance with at least min 100 objects. Each object has his own rectangle size.
(3) Moving objects and fixed objects are together in the quad node.

@agone For the grid structure you mean something like spatial hashing?

Spacial yes, but hash?(of pointers, interesting). Each cell in the grid is just a pointer to an array of element pointers. Every cell knows its neighbors by definition.(quad tree requires up then down to establish neighbors across 2^x boundaries) So updating positions for the grid is a simple modulus and division of each corner of the object(and verifying if the size is larger w or h than the grid, the middle cells are added. Once added, any movement speed(or change of position) < grid size, is a single remove and add per axis)
